# Alterar o Enabled do TControl ativa o evento do click sozinho

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Fala galera,

Ao alterar o botão(TButton) para desativado dentro de um evento , ele dispara outro evento.

```pascal
procedure TFormulario.OnButtonExecutarOperacaoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //...
  //aqui está o problema
  //a função abaixo é sincrona assim ele trava nesta linha porque chamou o evento denovo
  ButtonCancelar.Enabled:=true;//.Visible também tem o mesmo comportamento

  FuncaoQueNaoChamaPorCausaDesteProblema();
end;
```

Sem isto:

> ButtonCancelar.Enabled:=true

funciona normalmente.

**EDIT 1**: control.inc

```
procedure TControl.SetEnabled(Value: Boolean);  
begin
  if FEnabled <> Value
  then begin
    EnabledChanging; //aqui chama o evento do OnButtonExecutarOperacaoClick
    FEnabled := Value;
    Perform(CM_ENABLEDCHANGED, 0, 0);
    EnabledChanged;
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT 2** Descobri que só acontece isso quando o botão inicia com enable ou visible false. Agora a resolução ainda não faço ideia

**EDIT 3**

```
procedure TControl.EnabledChanging;
begin
  DoCallNotifyHandler(chtOnEnabledChanging);
end;

procedure TControl.DoCallNotifyHandler(HandlerType: TControlHandlerType);
begin
  FControlHandlers[HandlerType].CallNotifyEvents(Self);
end;
```

**EDIT 4**

Fazendo alguns testes, se eu duplicar o botão e executar um ou outro, o formulario só desativa o botão que disparar o evento, então se eu tenho **botao-A** e o **botao-B** e apertar o **botao-A** somente ele vai ficar desativado, mesmo que a função desative os dois.

Comment: Ele pega nessa linha, executa o evento que eu chamei (no caso o click do executarOperação) e até prossegue mas praticamente ele chama 2 eventos

Comment: Coloca o código das duas funções(`EnabledChanging` e `EnabledChanged`) também, olhei aqui na classe `TControl` no `delphi 7` e não existe essas duas chamadas.

Comment: Então, eu não coloquei nenhum evento nesses caras, vou editar e colocar os codigos

Comment: E o `EnabledChanged`?

Comment: cai no mesmo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi utilizando TTask.Run, depois de um tempo descobri que tinha uma função async dentro dos OnClick, ai na hora de chamar a "FuncaoQueNaoChamaPorCausaDesteProblema()" dentro dela ficou assim

```
procedure TForm1.FuncaoQueNaoChamaPorCausaDesteProblema();
begin
 TTask.Run(procedure
  begin
    //...

    DesabilitarBotoes();
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DesabilitarBotoes();
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
  begin
    //...
    ButtonCancelarOperacao.Enabled:= false;
  end);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Esse não é o comportamento padrão. Possivelmente, seu código está fazendo alguma chamada recursiva. Neste caso, você pode desabilitar temporariamente o handler do evento:

`procedure TFormulario.OnButtonExecutarOperacaoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ButtonCancelar.OnClick := nil; //verificar exatamente qual seria o evento recursivo
  try
    ButtonCancelar.Enabled := true;
  finally
    ButtonCancelar.OnClick := ButtonCancelarClick;
  end;
  FuncaoQueNaoChamaPorCausaDesteProblema();
end;`

Comment: coloquei mais um pouco de informação, fiz oq vc comentou mas ainda sim ele chamou denovo. O pior que eu criei esse botão do zero.